# Convert JSON String to Date type with Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, date, data-conversion

I am pulling a date from a JSON array called closeDate - using a subquery with `data->>'closeDate' as PortalCloseDate` which returns a string with the date format YYYY-MM-DD. I am trying to convert it to a date. When I return the column I have tried `cast(cls.PortalCloseDate as date)` and get the error message: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "‎2020-‎12-‎09"

I have also tried `to_date(cls.PortalCloseDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')` and `to_date(replace(cls.PortalCloseDate,'-',''),'YYYYMMDD')` but get the error message: ERROR: invalid value "‎2" for "YYYY" Detail: Value must be an integer.

I need this to be a date data type since I am using calculations to find the time between two dates. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I exported to csv and there are a few dates with a different format than the rest. [dates in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn0XR.png) For the majority of the dates they were automatically put in a date type but for the row with the date 2020-12-09 it was in a general format. I have attached a screenshot of the csv

Comment: Can you print the output of `SELECT cls.PortalCloseDate`? I ran the same command using dummy values on postgres and it worked fine, # SELECT TO_DATE('2020-12-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

So it's likely there's an issue with the data in that field.

Comment: @Blakedallen it looks like it could be data - I edited my post

Comment: There is some sort of encoding issue going on. When I copy and paste `‎2020-‎12-‎09` from your question I get the failures you see. When I enter `'2020-12-09` manually on my end everything works as it should. `‎2020-‎12-‎09` is a valid format for a date: `select '2020-12-09'::date; 2020-12-09`. Where are you getting the data from and how is getting into the database?